# Access violating reading when trying to deallocate a 2d array

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am trying to deallocate a 2nd array that was allocated using the following code:

```
int** createMatrix(int k)
{
    int i;
    int **res;

    res = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*k);
    checkalloc(res);

    for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        res[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*k);
        checkalloc(res[i]);
    }
    return res;
}
```

With the following function

```
void freeMatrix(int ***matrix, int k)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
        free(matrix[i]);

    free(matrix);
}
```

The first element is being deallocated well but when `i=1` the function crashes with the error:

```
First-chance exception at 0x0f7e7e2c (msvcr100d.dll) in Q2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xccccccc8.
Unhandled exception at 0x0f7e7e2c (msvcr100d.dll) in Q2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xccccccc8.
```

What am I doing wrong?

## EDIT:

Same happens to me when trying to deallocate a similar array that is allocated by:

```
CHARS** createImageMatrix(FILE *fp, int rows, int cols, int format)
{
    CHARS**res;
    int i;

    res = (CHARS**)malloc(sizeof(CHARS*)*rows);
    checkalloc(res);

    for (i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        res[i] = (CHARS*)malloc(sizeof(CHARS)*cols);
        checkalloc(res[i]);
    }
    return res;
}
```

and deallocating with:

```
void freeCharsMatrix(CHARS **matrix, int rows)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        free(matrix[i]);
    free(matrix);
}
```

when CHARS is:

```
typedef struct Chars {
char A;
char B;
char C;
char D;
```

} CHARS;

But this time I get:

[image: error]

What's wrong with me?

Comment: You don't have to cast the void* malloc returns in C.

Comment: @hetepeperfan, This is how I am required to allocate memory. This is not what's causing the crash.

Comment: You allocate a int** and subsequently freeing a int*** in you `free_matrix`

Comment: Typically, [three star programming](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer) is frowned upon, or it at least often indicates that something is wrong or there might be a better way to solve your problem.

Comment: You should have gotten a warning from your compiler that you were miscalling the `freeMatrix()` function if you simply passed the returned value (from `createMatrix()`) to `freeMatrix()`.  If you pass the address of the pointer to `freeMatrix()`, then maybe you should be zeroing the pointer after freeing the data — and using an extra level of indirection in `freeMatrix()`.  If you had compiler warnings about type mismatches and were ignoring them, you are doing no-one any good.  Remember, the C compiler knows more about C than you do (or I do)!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I was doing things totally wrong, sending freeMatrix() tha matrix I would like to deallocate with an ampersand as a pointer :|

Comment: `free(matrix+i);` this line is wrong

Comment: use `free(matrix[i])` instead of `free(matrix +1)` .

Comment: Your new `createImageMatrix` function takes `rows` and `cols` but allocates using `height` and `width`.  Are the latter two globals, or ... what?  And what are the file and format arguments for?

Comment: Oh, and your `createImageMatrix()` function does not return a value like it is supposed to.  Have you turned on all the compiler warnings?

Comment: @LidongGuo, I have tried - no success. The `+i` is my desperate try.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the height\width and rows\cols is just me copying wrong. The values are fine.

Comment: The variable `height` is  run-time known?

Comment: `void freeCharsMatrix(CHARS *matrix[height], int rows)` may help you if you know the height before compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void freeMatrix(int ***matrix, int k)

==>

void freeMatrix(int **matrix, int k)
```

---

Edit:

```
free(matrix+i) // when you do this the pointer across the whole array .
```

==>

```
free(matrix[i])
```

Comment: I was going nuts, HAWK EYE BADGE AWARDED ;-)

Comment: What can cause this error http://i.imgur.com/Ekx1aoj.png on the same program with the same 2D array only of a struct (of 3 ints) instead of int?

Comment: Edited, I am looking forward for your reference

Answer (score 1):

There are two primary problems with your 'ImageMatrix' example:

1. Your `createImageMatrix()` function doesn't return a value.
2. Your `freeCharsMatrix()` function calls `free(matrix+i)` when it should use `free(matrix[i])` or `free(*(matrix+i))`.

Your subsidiary problems are compilation related:

1. `createImageMatrix()` does not use the `fp` or `format` arguments.
2. The body of the function is written in terms of `height` and `width` but the arguments are `rows` and `cols`.

Here is a debug-laden version of your code.  I've renamed `freeCharsMatrix()` to `freeImageMatrix()` so the names are more consistent.  When I was doing my main testing, the `func_name` references were spelled `__func__`, but that's a C99 feature (allowed by GCC 4.8.1 even with `-std=c89 -pedantic`), so I renamed the variable and provided the explicit definitions since you are most likely working with a C89 compiler (MSVC only supports the 23 year old standard, not the 13 year old standard or the 1 year old standard).

You can see how I ended up diagnosing the problem — printing out the addresses passed to `free()` and comparing them with those returned by `malloc()`.  It took me an embarrassingly long time to spot that `matrix[i]` is equivalent to `*(matrix+i)` and not `matrix+i`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Chars
{
    char A;
    char B;
    char C;
    char D;
} CHARS;

void dumpImageMatrix(CHARS **matrix, int rows, int cols);
CHARS **createImageMatrix(int height, int width);
void freeImageMatrix(CHARS **matrix, int height);

static void dump_address(const char *tag, int num, void *vp)
{
    printf("%s[%d] = %p\n", tag, num, vp);
}

static void checkalloc(void *vp)
{
    if (vp == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

CHARS **createImageMatrix(int height, int width)
{
    static const char func_name[] = "createImageMatrix";
    CHARS **res;
    int i;

    printf("-->> %s()\n", func_name);
    res = (CHARS**)malloc(sizeof(CHARS*)*height);
    checkalloc(res);
    dump_address("MTX", 0, res);

    for (i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        int j;
        res[i] = (CHARS*)malloc(sizeof(CHARS)*width);
        checkalloc(res[i]);
        dump_address("Row", i, res[i]);
        for (j = 0; j < width; j++)
            memset(&res[i][j], (i + j) % 26 + 'A', sizeof(CHARS));
    }
    printf("<<-- %s()\n", func_name);
    return res;
}

void freeImageMatrix(CHARS **matrix, int height)
{
    static const char func_name[] = "freeImageMatrix";
    int i;
    printf("-->> %s()\n", func_name);
    for (i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        dump_address("Row", i, matrix[i]);
        /*dump_address("CHK", i, matrix+i);*/
        /*dump_address("CHK", i, *(matrix+i));*/
        /*free(matrix[i]);*/
        free(*(matrix+i));
        /*free(matrix+i);*/
    }
    dump_address("MTX", 0, matrix);
    free(matrix);
    printf("<<-- %s()\n", func_name);
}

int main(void)
{
    enum { m_rows = 5, m_cols = 6 };
    CHARS **mat = createImageMatrix(m_rows, m_cols);
    dumpImageMatrix(mat, m_rows, m_cols);
    freeImageMatrix(mat, m_rows);
    return 0;
}

static void dump_Chars(CHARS c)
{
    printf("%c%c%c%c", c.A, c.B, c.C, c.D);
}

void dumpImageMatrix(CHARS **matrix, int rows, int cols)
{
    static const char func_name[] = "dumpImageMatrix";
    int i;
    printf("-->> %s()\n", func_name);
    dump_address("MTX", 0, matrix);
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        int j;
        dump_address("Row", i, matrix[i]);
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            if (j != 0)
                putchar(' ');
            dump_Chars(matrix[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    printf("<<-- %s()\n", func_name);
}
```

Sample output:

```
-->> createImageMatrix()
MTX[0] = 0x7f97cb4039d0
Row[0] = 0x7f97cb403a00
Row[1] = 0x7f97cb403a20
Row[2] = 0x7f97cb403a40
Row[3] = 0x7f97cb403a60
Row[4] = 0x7f97cb403a80
<<-- createImageMatrix()
-->> dumpImageMatrix()
MTX[0] = 0x7f97cb4039d0
Row[0] = 0x7f97cb403a00
AAAA BBBB CCCC DDDD EEEE FFFF
Row[1] = 0x7f97cb403a20
BBBB CCCC DDDD EEEE FFFF GGGG
Row[2] = 0x7f97cb403a40
CCCC DDDD EEEE FFFF GGGG HHHH
Row[3] = 0x7f97cb403a60
DDDD EEEE FFFF GGGG HHHH IIII
Row[4] = 0x7f97cb403a80
EEEE FFFF GGGG HHHH IIII JJJJ
<<-- dumpImageMatrix()
-->> freeImageMatrix()
Row[0] = 0x7f97cb403a00
Row[1] = 0x7f97cb403a20
Row[2] = 0x7f97cb403a40
Row[3] = 0x7f97cb403a60
Row[4] = 0x7f97cb403a80
MTX[0] = 0x7f97cb4039d0
<<-- freeImageMatrix()
```

Comment: This is what I get when I try to work with your `printf()` debugging method: http://i.imgur.com/MEWjaKX.png As we can see the first address crashes the application with heap error. I would like to ask your forgiveness for the typos (that were fixed) in the edited code that occurred due to the very late hour I wrote the question.